How to transform coordinates in the Action equation?
For a particle moving in one dimension, and we have two people describing the motion of that particle one is stationary (let's call him Lenny) and the other (George) is moving relative to Lenny. Lenny's using the coordinate $x$, while George's using the coordinate $X$. Where we have:
$$X(t) = x(t) - f(t)\tag{p.117}$$
If we have the Action:
$$A = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\frac{1}{2}m(\dot X + \dot f)^2 - V(X)dt\tag{p.117}$$
The equation above describes the action from Lenny's point of view, or from George's?
Doesn't this equation describes the kinetic energy from Lenny's point of view and the potential energy from
George's point of view?
References:

Susskind, The Theoretical Minimum, Page 117.


I believe the action you wrote is wrong. the transformations are not applied properly.

But I just copied the equation from a book called The Theoretical Minimum Page 117. @Charu_Bamble

can you please share the text with a link or something, it's not clear.

https://t.me/principleofleastaction/2 @Charu_Bamble

This could be the Lagrangian from Lenny's point of view, if:

the transformation of coordinates is
$$x = X + f$$
and you wrote the wrong sign in your question

the potential is written with some abuse of notation as
$$V(x) = V(X+f) = \tilde{V}(X)$$
stressing that the potential as a function of $x$ and the potential as a function of $X$ is represented by different functions (one function is the composition of the other function with the rule of coordinate transformation).


Just make the choice of one set of coordinates and use it. Otherwise, you need to add the rule of coordinate transformation as a constraint in the action.

Yes i wrote the wrong sign, sorry for that. But can you tell me V(x) = V(X) i did not uderstand this part of your answer

Please, read carefully $V(x) = V(X+f) = \tilde{V}(X)$, i.e. the coordinate transformation is involved, and the tilde above $\tilde{V}$ indicates that it is a different function w.r.t. $V$, because it's independent variable $X$ is related to the independent variable $x$ with the transformation of coords

The author said that the potential energy $V(X)$ in the equation means the potential energy that Lenny would use, evaluated at the object's location, but expressed in George's coordinates-same points, different label. I don't think that you and the author are saying the same thing, and don't really know what the author meant by this phrase.
